# Node : new page with new html file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing an app with nodeJS. I have an html file for my main page. Now, I want to call a new page (using a new html file) when I double-click on a button.

**Here is my code:**

Double-click button, client side:

```
$scope.dblclick = function(env){
    console.log("double-click is working")
    console.log("Here is my env")
    console.log(env)

    env = encodeURIComponent(env) // encode

    $http.get('/detailenv/' + env) //call a new page, with a new html file
    .success(function(data){
        console.log("success")
    })
    .error(function(data){
        console.log('http detailenv is a failure ')
        console.log('Error: ');
    });

}
```

Server-side:

```
app.get('/detailenv/:env', function(req, res){
console.log("OK")
res.sendfile(__dirname + '/test.html')
});
```

The problem is that nothing happens. The double-click works, I received the "OK" message, but my test html file is not loaded.

I want to add that to handle the other routes, I put in my code :

```
app.configure(function(){
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
});
```

I don't know if the problem could come from here

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you must have gotten an error back from node correct? what was it?

Comment: Do you have some information on your terminal's log?

Comment: no, no errors, nothing... everything works except that the page is not loaded O_o

Comment: Youre not even getting a 404?

Comment: no, 0 error. But I think I have found the problem... I think it might be a problem of callback : like tu file doesn't have the time to load, or something like this...I will try another way :/